# A word to describe believing that two events occurring at the same time are linked to each other while they are not correlated at all

Tags: single-word-requests

A word to describe believing that two events occurring at the same time are linked to each other while they are not correlated at all.

For example: Bob walks on the street and yells at someone who wasn't doing anything wrong. He trips and falls. He believes this is karma. Him believing this is because of karma is called ....

Comment: ... a coincidence?

Comment: The focus is on the act of believing that it is correlated rather than the events themselve. I edited the example to reflect this better.

Comment: It's still not quite clear what you're asking. I have posted a an answer describing the type of logical fallacy - but it could be simply called **a superstition**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A word that describes a statement that is untrue based on anecdotal evidence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/463853/a-word-that-describes-a-statement-that-is-untrue-based-on-anecdotal-evidence)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ***[Post hoc ergo propter hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc)*** (Latin: "after this, therefore because of this") is a logical fallacy that states "*Since event Y
>   followed event X, event Y must have been caused by event X*." It is
>   often shortened simply to ***post hoc fallacy***.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a [cognitive bias](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases) and I think the one you’re specifically describing is [attentional bias](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attentional_bias). Where Bob, feeling guilty and thinking about shouting at some innocent, interprets his misfortune as a result. Or it could be confirmation bias if Bob already has a firm belief in karma and frames events in such a way as to confirm his existing belief.

Answer (score 0):

a **superstition**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/superstition)

> 1. An irrational belief that an object, action, or circumstance not logically related to a course of events influences its outcome.

As in:

> Bob, a believer in superstitions, blames his tripping on karma!